# Converting objective-c frameworks and third party code to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I know those objective-c files must be converted to swift manually (with some help from several online converting tools),
the question is...

how about frameworks that're added to the project?
And third parties written in objective-c added via cocoapods?

[image]

Do I need to remove those frameworks, re-add third parties of their swift version, or let Xcode warn me with any possible error?
Maybe just keep them and add some bridge file to cope with those?

Need some information before I mess everything up...

Any link or file guide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obj-c frameworks can all be used in swift and will automatically be bridged to swift so you can access them from swift code (create an obj-c bridge, google it). You can add your own .h files to this obj-c bridge file too and use your obj-c code in swift. There's no need to search for swift libraries or anything.